# How to know if UITableView is being scrolled manually (by hand) or programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I am using a UITableView in my code and it would be nice to know if the user manually scrolled the UITableView or it was done programmatically. Is there a way to know that?

Answer (score 38):

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView.
so you can use this

```
if (!tableView.isDragging && !tableView.isDecelerating)
{
   // the table is *not* being scrolled
}
```

this works. i use it in one of my apps.

Answer (score 9):

You can implement following method of UIScrollViewDelegate, to know about the scrolling of your table view:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)activeScrollView
```

Don't forget to put this on too...

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Hope it helps, cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

Use this to detect both fast and slow scrolling caused by user interaction:

```
if tableView.isDragging, tableView.isDecelerating || tableView.isTracking {
    // Table view is scrolled by user, not by code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Best method I've found is to use the `isTracking` property rather than `isDragging`.

```
if tableView.isTracking && tableView.isDecelerating {
    // Table was scrolled by user.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I checked `tableView.isTracking` and `tableView.isDecelerating` inside 
[scrollViewDidScroll](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll?language=objc). However, it didn't work for me if the user only slightly moved the tableview. Since a scrollView has a panGesture we can check the velocity of that gesture. If the tableView was programmatically scrolled the velocity in both x and y directions is 0.0. By checking this velocity we can determine if the user scrolled the tableView because the panGesture has a velocity.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let velocity = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.velocity(in: tableView)
    print("Velocity: \(velocity)")
    if velocity.x != 0.0 || velocity.y != 0.0 {
        // user scrolled the tableview
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could activate a tap recognizer, detecting all touches registered.

If the tableview scrolls, but no touchgestures are involved, it should cover it.